# How to change an edittext border colour to red on error?

Tags: android, android-edittext

so the edit text box border should change as in the picture to red when validated that is during an error and also when the text entered is empty.

[image]

Comment: have you tried anything so far? Please post your code

Comment: you need to create background xml for that when your want error show set error background to editext when its valid thn show other background to editext

Comment: @Nilu how to set  error background to edit text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create two seprate background like this

**error background**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ff00" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

**normal background**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#0059ff" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

Try this

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(edittext.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                edittext.setError("error");
                edittext.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edterr);
            }else {
                edittext.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edtnormal);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: thank u I'll try this .

Comment: @ShriyaD.S let me know in case of any query

Comment: @ShriyaD.S did it work

Comment: itz working thanks @Nilu

Comment: @ShriyaD.S happy to help you

Comment: edit text box colour is changing.. but i have placed this edit text box in a relative layout ..When error occurs  how to change the color of relative layout to red instead of edit box ?

Comment: @ShriyaD.S than set background of relative layout instead of ediyttext